# Invalid operation id format. Choose a valid operation id android management api

Tags: android-management-api

I am running device operation api and getting this response

my response is -

**{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid operation id format. Choose a valid operation id.",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
}**

my request body is -

curl 
'https://androidmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/LC021x5h57/devices/36a36c5bdf986911/operations?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' 
--header 'Accept: application/json' 
--compressed

Comment: what is the operation id ??

Answer (score 1):

[Operations ID](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices.operations#resource:-operation) is part of the server-assigned name, which is only unique within the same service that originally returns it. The parameter `name` when using the [enterprise.operations.get](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices.operations/get) is generated after using [issueCommand](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/issueCommand) and is included in the API response.